# How can I use memalign?

Tags: c++

I would like to know which header I need to include in my `.cpp` file to be able to use the `memalign` function.

```
#include <???> // unknown lib

void  Foo(void)
{
  /***/
  mem = (char*)memalign(0x100, size);
  /***/
}
```

Comment: `#include <malloc.h>` https://linux.die.net/man/3/memalign

Answer (score 4):

`memalign` is not a standard function. It is not in C++, C, nor even in POSIX standard. As such, the first step is to use a system that provides such non-standard function. For example, Linux and BSD do have it. It comes with the C standard library. As per documentation, it is in the `<malloc>` header.

However, don't use `memalign` in C++. Instead, use `new`.

Or, if you for some reason need a C allocation function (which is unlikely), then use the standard `std::aligned_alloc`.

Comment: you can use operator new with an explicit alignment, too. std::aligned_alloc is only for C compatibility...